# How do insert and retrieve checkbox value using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

My problem is, I key in the sibling details in the first row textboxs and i select the check box no error display. If i didn't select the checkbox its display the below error. Can you give some idea? i am new for CodeIgniter.

I got error message: (How i can solve the error)

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 1
Filename: controllers/registration.php
Line Number: 288
```

Below my Code:

```
foreach($querystud_frm->result() as $row)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>".$i.")</td>";
            $data=array('name'=>'s_sibling_name[]','class'=>'textbox','value'=>$row->s_sibling_name,'style'=>'text-transform:uppercase;');
            echo "<td >".form_input($data)."</td>";
            $data=array('name'=>'s_sibling_nric[]','class'=>'textbox','value'=>$row->s_sibling_nric,'style'=>'text-transform:uppercase;');
            echo "<td >".form_input($data)."</td>";
            $sib_dob=date('d-m-Y',strtotime(trim($row->s_sibling_dob)));
            $data=array('name'=>'s_sibling_dob[]','class'=>'textbox','value'=>$sib_dob,'style'=>'text-transform:uppercase;');
            echo "<td >".form_input($data)."</td>";
            $data=array('name'=>'s_sibling_relation[]','class'=>'textbox','value'=>$row->s_sibling_relation,'style'=>'text-transform:uppercase;');
            echo "<td >".form_input($data)."</td>";
            $data=array('name'=>'s_sibling_occupation[]','class'=>'textbox','value'=>$row->s_sibling_occupation,'style'=>'text-transform:uppercase;');
            echo "<td >".form_input($data)."</td>";
            $data=array('name'=>'s_sibling_income[]','class'=>'textbox','value'=>$row->s_sibling_income,'style'=>'text-transform:uppercase;');
            echo "<td >".form_input($data)."</td>";
                $sib_yes = $row->s_sibling_yes;
            echo $sib_yes;
            if($sib_yes == 'YES')
            {
            $data= array('name' => 's_sibling_yes[]', 'id' => 's_sibling_yes', 'value' => 'YES', 'checked' => TRUE);
            echo "<td >".form_checkbox($data)."</td>";
            }
            else
            {
            $data= array('name' => 's_sibling_yes[]', 'id' => 's_sibling_yes', 'value' => 'NO', 'checked' => FALSE);
            echo "<td >".form_checkbox($data)."</td>";
            }

    echo "</tr>"; 
                $i++;
        }

        if($i<10)
        {
            $var=array("s_sibling_name","s_sibling_nric","s_sibling_dob","s_sibling_relation","s_sibling_occupation","s_sibling_income");
            for($j=$i;$j<=10;$j++)
            {
                echo "<tr><td>".$j.")</td>";
                foreach($var as $value)
                {
                    $value=$value.'[]';
                $data_val=array('name'=>$value,'class'=>'textbox','value'=>'','style'=>'text-transform:uppercase;');
                echo "<td>".form_input($data_val)."</td>";
                }
            if($sib_yes == 'YES')
            {
            $data= array('name' => 's_sibling_yes[]', 'id' => 's_sibling_yes', 'value' => 'YES', 'checked' => TRUE);
            echo "<td >".form_checkbox($data)."</td>";
            }
            else
            {
            $data= array('name' => 's_sibling_yes[]', 'id' => 's_sibling_yes', 'value' => 'NO', 'checked' => FALSE);
            echo "<td >".form_checkbox($data)."</td>";
            }

    echo "</tr>"; 
            }
            unset($var);
        }

        $querystud_frm->free_result();
    }
    else 
    {
        $var=array("s_sibling_name","s_sibling_nric","s_sibling_dob","s_sibling_relation","s_sibling_occupation","s_sibling_income");
        $var_sib=array("s_sibling_yes");            
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>".$i.")</td>";
            foreach($var as $value)
            {
                $name=$value.'[]';  
                $data=array('name'=>$name,'class'=>'textbox','value'=>'','style'=>'text-transform:uppercase;');
                echo "<td >".form_input($data)."</td>";
            }
                $data= array('name' => 's_sibling_yes[]', 'id' => 's_sibling_yes', 'value' => 'YES', 'checked' => FALSE);
                echo "<td >".form_checkbox($data)."</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 

        }
        unset($var,$i,$data,$var_sib);
    }
```

controller/registration.php

```
            if($this->input->post('siblingsfrm'))
        {
            $this->data['nric']=$this->input->post('s_nric');
            //echo $this->input->post('name');
            $name=$this->input->post('s_sibling_name');
            $nric=$this->input->post('s_sibling_nric');
            $dob=$this->input->post('s_sibling_dob');
            //$dob=strtotime($dob);
            //$dob=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dob));
            $relation=$this->input->post('s_sibling_relation');
            $occupation=$this->input->post('s_sibling_occupation');
            $income=$this->input->post('s_sibling_income');
            $sib_yes=$this->input->post('s_sibling_yes');
            $sib_id=$this->input->post('s_sibling_id');
            //print_r($sib_id);
            //print_r($name);
            //exit();
            //$this->load->helper('date');
            for($i=0;$i<count($name);$i++)
            {
                if($name[$i]!='')
                {
                    $income[$i]=trim($income[$i]);
                    if($income[$i]=='')
                    $income[$i]=0;
                    if($sib_yes[$i]!= 'YES')
                    $sib_yes[$i]='NO';
                    $date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime(trim($dob[$i])));
                $insert_values=array('s_nric'=>$this->data['nric'],'s_sibling_name'=>strtoupper(trim($name[$i])),
                                    's_sibling_nric'=>strtoupper(trim($nric[$i])),'s_sibling_dob'=>$date,
                                    's_sibling_relation'=>strtoupper(trim($relation[$i])),
                                    's_sibling_occupation'=>strtoupper(trim($occupation[$i])),
                                    's_sibling_income'=>strtoupper(trim($income[$i])),
                                    's_sibling_yes'=>trim($sib_yes[$i]));
                if(is_array($sib_id) && isset($sib_id[$i]) )
                {
                    $where=array('s_sibling_id'=>$sib_id[$i]);
                    $this->db->update('si_student_siblings',$insert_values,$where);
                }
                else
                {
                    //print_r($insert_values);
                    $this->db->insert('si_student_siblings',$insert_values);
                }
                }
            }
            $this->data['level']=7;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if a checkbox wasn't checked, it won't send any data at all to the server.  So, this line of code...

```
$name=$this->input->post('s_sibling_name');
```

...will actually set the `$name` variable to `FALSE` (see *$this->input->post()* documentation in [the guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html))

Thus, the first time through your loop, your code is looking for the array item at `$name[0]`, when in fact `$name` is not even an array, it's `FALSE`.

You could surround your for loop with an if/else statement to solve this problem (not the most elegant solution, but it would work):

```
if (is_array($name) && count($name) > 0)
{
  for($i=0;$i<count($name);$i++)
  {
    if($name[$i]!='')
      //etcetera...
  }
}
```